# Opera showing a single cell per table row

Tags: html, opera

I'm not really "supporting" the old version of my project, but one of my users came to me with this screenshot:

[screenshot http://www.ezimba.com/work/140502C/ezimba18438212830500.png](http://www.ezimba.com/work/140502C/ezimba18438212830500.png)

As you can see, for some reason, the table is rendering with a single cell on each row. You can also see a similar effect on the semi-transparent "toolbar" at the bottom of the page, where the "bookmarks", "user status", "Apps", "Friends", "Notifications" and "site status" cells are each on their own row, causing the bar to be a lot taller than it should be. [EDIT: The user tells me that this apparently happens on all sites they visit.]

Anyway, I am not an Opera user and the only mention I can find on The Google is [this email archive](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/14197) from 2002 where the developer was basically "it works fine for me" about the problem. Kinda reminds me of [this xkcd strip](https://xkcd.com/979/) if I'm honest.

Anyway, I just figured I'd ask if anyone here has heard of this problem, encountered this problem, or even by chance resolved this problem and could help me figure out what's going on? Last thing I want is this bug creeping into newer projects ;)

Comment: I just tested this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/v2dm9/) in Opera and it works fine. Maybe you have a problem in CSS. I succeed to recreate your problem when I set `td { float: left; clear: both; }`.

Comment: I'd tell the user to use a proper browser!  But could be caused by empty cells - some browsers need a non breaking space in empty cells

Comment: @Pete "Some browsers need a non breaking space in empty cells" True.

Comment: @Pete No empty cells - as you can see they all have content.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Also true :)

Comment: Could be that opaque addon that could be destroying it

Comment: "That opaque addon"? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User resolved the issue with this option:

[screenshot http://www.ezimba.com/work/140502C/ezimba18438222149900.png](http://www.ezimba.com/work/140502C/ezimba18438222149900.png)

That said, I have no idea what the option reads XD Anyway, thanks to the people who took the time to comment above.